# REST resource to return Accounts with Hierarchy

Tags: rest-api

I'm trying to create REST API where I will return all accounts with `Type = Parent` and their child accounts.

I have Account Hierarchy in place and I'm confused on how to return Parent account A and child accounts x,y,z which have `parentID = A.Id` in single call.

I'm returning Multiple parent accounts and their child accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into the low level of implementation details, if I had to solve this requirement, I would return a JSON from the API. Assuming you already have the logic to pull the hierarchy for parent and their child accounts in place, you could create a JSON response which would consist of the Parent accounts and their Child accounts in an array. A sample structure would have looked liked as below:

```
{
  "1Parent": [
    "1Child1",
    "1Child2"
  ],
  "2Parent": [
    "2Child1",
    "2Child2"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two part answers.

1. You can use soql child relationship query to get all associated child accounts for given account. By adding `Type = Parent` predicate, you are selecting parents its children. Keep in mind this can lead to limit issues if you have lots of child records.
2. Returning this information in rest response is pretty straight forward. You can return the parent objects itself, which should serialize into json. Or you could create class to represent the format for full control and return those entities.